# Is there any ways that we can improve `std::getline`?

Tags: c++, getline

From `std::getline`'s [introduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), seems that it will erase std::string everytime, which involves lots of alloc/dealloc.

I wonder is there any way that I can improve this? For example I can always reserve K bytes, and if K if not enough, it will automaticlly expand.

However, seems getline's `char*` version is not suitable here, because we must pre-allocate fixed length.

Comment: *which involves lots of alloc/dealloc* - What makes you think so?

Comment: `std::basic_string::erase()` does not necessarily deallocate (and I think it will never actually deallocate anything). String keeps memory reserved like vector for quick `push_back()`.

Comment: Hi @Evg, I perf my program and find there are many construction/destruction of `basic_string`, which I think is caused by getline

Comment: @calvin then show the code and the output.

Comment: If you see `~basic_string()` calls, that cannot be due to `erase()`. Are you passing strings by value in your program?

Comment: No improvement needed. `getline()` will reuse the same buffer in reading different strings (which is why you must assign to storage and not rely on the internal buffer used by `getline()`. With `mmap` providing much of the allocated space now, the penalty isn't nearly as acute as when it was all `malloc()` `free()` under the hood.

Comment: please show a [mre] of the program causing a problem

Comment: `std::getline` takes a **reference** to an outside `std::string` object that it manipulates. There's no reason for it to create or destroy any `std::string` objects. The construction/destruction of `basic_string` is being done somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe going:  `std::string buffer; buffer.reserve(size);` Increasing the buffer size, could improve performance, due to the fact it needs to resize the string not that often?